# How do I make this ghostType jquery function do line breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with a jquery function called [ghostType](http://ghosttype.com) which basically types out text as though it is being typed on screen. Its kinda cool, but I can't seem to have it do line breaks.

The jquery is as follows:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.ghostType = function() {

    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var str = $this.text();
        $this.empty().show();
        str = str.split("");
        str.push("_");

        // increase the delay to ghostType slower
        var delay = 100;

        $.each(str, function (i, val) {
            if (val == "^") {
                // Do nothing. This will add to the delay.
            }
            else {
                $this.append('<span>' + val + '</span>');
                $this.children("span").hide().fadeIn(100).delay(delay * i);

            }
        });
        $this.children("span:last").css("textDecoration", "blink");

    });

};
})( jQuery );
```

From what I can tell this code takes each character in the chosen elements TEXT and puts it into seperate  tags, therefor omitting the HTML (ie br's) with the line var str = $this.text();

How would you go about making this code include line breaks?

The best I could come up with was by adding an extra 'else if' statement like so:

```
            else if ( val == "*" ) {
                $this.append('<br />');
            }
```

And therefor * signs would become line breaks... but this damages the functionality where blinking cursor doesn't sit beside each letter as it fades in. otherwise, it works...

You can see an example of what I've done at http://jsfiddle.net/JNyQV/

Comment: Still need the code? Have some spare time and I can try to see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would write the script... just add the entire partial string instead of each individual letter. The biggest difference is that the last letter doesn't fade in. I didn't think the effect was that noticeable, but it should be possible to just add the last letter and have that fade in if it is a necessity. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/JNyQV/1/).

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ghostType = function() {

        return this.each(function() {

            // increase the delay to ghostType slower
            var delay = 55,

            $this = $(this),
            str = $this.text(),
            i = 0,
            l = str.length,
            t,
            loop = function() {
                if (i <= l) {
                    t = str.substring(0,i++).replace(/\^/g, '').replace(/\*/g, '<br>');
                    $this.html(t + '<span class="blink" >_</span>');
                    setTimeout(loop, delay);
                }
            };

            $this.empty().show();
            loop();
        });

    };
})(jQuery);

$('#example').ghostType();
```

Comment: The fade isn't important anyways.. and your solution seems to be a lot less code. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.ghostType = function() {

    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var str = $this.text();
        $this.empty().show();
        str = str.split("");
        str.push("_");

        // increase the delay to ghostType slower
        var delay = 55;

        $.each(str, function (i, val) {
            if (val == "^") {
                // Do nothing. This will add to the delay.
            }
            else {
                if (val == "*") val = "<br/>";
                $this.append('<span>' + val + '</span>');
                $this.children("span").hide().fadeIn(100).delay(delay * i);

            }
        });
        $this.children("span:last").css("textDecoration", "blink");

    });

};
})( jQuery );

$('#example').ghostType();
```

Comment: Its partially correct. But I can get the line break in but it ruins the blinking span which follows the text as it types. If you click the link example on jsfiddle you can see how the cursor doesn't move along with the typed text.

Comment: In this solution Bemmu is including an "if" statement within the "else" instead of adding an "else if". This does not cause a problem with the cursor because the <br /> is added to the queue (as a val) instead of being displayed right away (as in Keen's fiddle). I would say this is the most accurate solution based on the original plugin. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2wGMu/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to treat the selected element as an element, and not just simply grab its text.

Here is an excerpt from [one of my plugins](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/bumpyText/blob/master/jquery.bumpytext.js#L20) that handles text...

```
var findText = function(element, pattern, callback) {
    for (var childi= element.childNodes.length; childi-->0;) {
        var child= element.childNodes[childi];
        if (child.nodeType==1) {
            findText(child, pattern, callback);
        } else if (child.nodeType==3) {
            var matches= [];
            var match;
            while (match= pattern.exec(child.data))
                matches.push(match);
            for (var i= matches.length; i-->0;)
                callback.call(window, child, matches[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I originally got this piece of code from an answer here by [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince).

By examining the rest of [my plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/bumpyText/blob/master/jquery.bumpytext.js), you should be able to pick up how it works. Basically, it iterates over all text nodes recursively, wrapping each character in a `span` which is later animated.

Comment: thanks for this. your code looks really simple but I can't read it as I'm not that advanced!